# Is there a closed-form function to convert itertools combination into an index?

Tags: python, indexing, probability, python-itertools, combinatorics

I am currently using the itertools.combinations() function in python, and would like to access the index of a particular combination using the resulting combination. Here is an example:

Using this code to generate indices and their corresponding combination:

```
it = itertools.combinations(range(6),2)

for i in enumerate(it):
    print(i)
```

Result:

```
(0, (0, 1, 2, 3))
(1, (0, 1, 2, 4))
(2, (0, 1, 2, 5))
(3, (0, 1, 3, 4))
(4, (0, 1, 3, 5))
(5, (0, 1, 4, 5))
(6, (0, 2, 3, 4))
(7, (0, 2, 3, 5))
(8, (0, 2, 4, 5))
(9, (0, 3, 4, 5))
(10, (1, 2, 3, 4))
(11, (1, 2, 3, 5))
(12, (1, 2, 4, 5))
(13, (1, 3, 4, 5))
(14, (2, 3, 4, 5))
```

I would like to be able to use the sorted tuple (0, 3, 4, 5) to *efficiently* map to the index 9. Is there a closed-form function that I can generalize to accomplish this? I originally tried a multi-index, but when generalized to a large combinations object this was impractically slow.

As a potential starting point for determining such a function, while messing around and thinking about the problem, I realized that the number of times each first digit (d1) occurs can be represented as (n-(d1 + 1) choose p-1). In this example n = 6 and p = 4, so there are (5 choose 3) or 10 occurrences of 0, and 4 choose 3 or 4 occurrences of 1, and so-on. I could not determine an easy way to generalize this for d2-4 where values are repeated, or to convert this to an index.

Comment: This seems more like a [math.se] question.

Answer (score 1):

This could be solved by dynamic programming. Say your combination has length `p` with the structure: `(c_0, c_1, c_2, ..., c_{p-1})`. First you compute number of iterations that are less than `(c_0, c_0+1, c_0+2, ..., c_0+p-1)`. After, you reduce your array to `(c_1, c_2, ..., c_{p-1})-c_0-1`. Then do the same thing until the length of your array is 1.

```
from math import comb
import numpy as np
import itertools

def find_niterations_before_c0(max_val, p, c0):
    '''
    Suppose combination_i = (c_0, c_1, c_2, ..., c_{p-1})
    This function will return the number of combinations before
    (c_0, c_0+1, c_0+2, ..., c_{p-1}+p-1)
    '''
    n = max_val
    k = max_val-p+1
    return sum([comb(n-i,k-i) for i in range(c0)])

def get_index(combination_i, stop):
    # This function finds the position of the given combination using DP
    # Suppose range <stop> = 6 and combination_i = (1,2,3,5)
    # 1. Calculate number of iterations before (1,2,3,4) which is 10
    # 2. Reduce combination to (0,1,3) and new <stop> = 4
    # 3. Calculate number of iterations before (0,1,2) which is 0
    # 4. Reduce combination to (0,2) and new <stop> = 3
    # 5. Calculate number of iterations before (0, 1) which is 0
    # 6. Reduce combinations to (1,) and new <stop> = 2
    # 7. Calculate number of iterations before (1, ) which is 1
    # 8. Array length is 1. Return total iterations.    
    
    combination_i = np.array(combination_i)
    ret = 0
    while(True):
        p = len(combination_i)
        ret += find_niterations_before_c0(stop-1, p, combination_i[0])
        stop = stop - 1 - combination_i[0]
        combination_i = combination_i[1:] - 1 - combination_i[0]
        if p == 1:
            return ret
```

Here is an example run:

```
stop = 6
p = 4
it = itertools.combinations(range(stop), p)

for combination_i in it:
    ind = get_index(combination_i, stop)
    print(ind, combination_i)
```

`[Output]:`

```
0 (0, 1, 2, 3)
1 (0, 1, 2, 4)
2 (0, 1, 2, 5)
3 (0, 1, 3, 4)
4 (0, 1, 3, 5)
5 (0, 1, 4, 5)
6 (0, 2, 3, 4)
7 (0, 2, 3, 5)
8 (0, 2, 4, 5)
9 (0, 3, 4, 5)
10 (1, 2, 3, 4)
11 (1, 2, 3, 5)
12 (1, 2, 4, 5)
13 (1, 3, 4, 5)
14 (2, 3, 4, 5)
```

You could also calculate for very large number.

```
get_index((6, 10, 12, 13, 16, 50), 60)
```

`[Output]:`

```
25005038
```