# Itertools combinations find if a combination is divisible

Tags: python, combinations

Given itertools combinations with an r of 4:

```
from itertools import combinations

mylist = range(0,35) 
r = 4
combinationslist = list(combinations(mylist, r))
```

Which will output:

```
(0, 1, 2, 3)
(0, 1, 2, 4)
(0, 1, 2, 5)
(0, 1, 2, 6)
(0, 1, 2, 7)
(0, 1, 2, 8)
(0, 1, 2, 9)
...
(30, 31, 32, 33)
(30, 31, 32, 34)
(30, 31, 33, 34)
(30, 32, 33, 34)
(31, 32, 33, 34)
```

My question is if we were to chunk to the list into blocks of 10 can we find what nth a combination is within those blocks, but without generating all combinations. Or in another words if the position is divisible by x.

One of the problems with this is the positions will get into the billions of billions and might not be possible to derive what the nth is. Is there a heuristic that can regardless find whether a particular combination/sequence of elements is divisible by x

Edit/addition: The reasoning for this question is for situations where the list is range(0,1000000) and r =30000 for example. Then provided a combination, find if it's divisible by x. Naturally the actual index will be ridiculously enormous (and the full combinations too much to generate)

Comment: In other words, given a permutation, find at which position in the list of all permutations it would occur? What do you mean when you say that a combination is divisible? Do you mean it's position?

Comment: Yes but the positions will run into the millions of billions. So I was wondering if there was a way to find out whether it's a position divisible by 5 or 7 etc. A heuristic perhaps just based on the last position. The original list will always be integers 0-x

Comment: Or to take an example is it possible to find whether '(5, 8, 24, 28)' is divisible by 5 without first getting its position, based on the logic of the order of the itertools combinations

Comment: When you say position, do you mean the index in the list?

Comment: Of course you can.  In your example, there are 34*33*32 entries that start with 0.  There are 33*32*31 entries that start with 1.  Thus, the first 5 entry (5,6,7,8) will be entry number 150,750.  It's just math.

Comment: Simpler statement of the question: `combinations()` generated a 4-tuple in the `i`th position. Given the `(a, b, c, d)` tuple, predict the index `i`. (And then as Tim Roberts observes, computing "i mod k" is trivial.)

Comment: @TimRoberts thanks! What if the list was enormous though and the r too. For instance:

mylist = range(0,1000000) 
r=20,000

Is there a way to shortcut it and just know if a permutation is divisible by a certain number?

Comment: That IS the way to shortcut it.  There is no magic one-liner here.  Your example has 1.1 million entries, but we can figure out the entry with a few hundred computations.

Comment: Your edit mentions permutations; your original question mentions only combinations.  Which is it?  The two are not at all equivalent questions.

Comment: Because provided a combination of 30,000 I want to find out how many steps away it is from every 6th combination of combinations(range(1000000), 30000). Of course, if I could create all the combinations, which I can't then I would already know every 6th etc.

Comment: @RodrigoRodrigues Huh? It's 58516 digits long and `math.comb(1000000, 30000)` finishes in under a second on a macbook air. That's a big number, but not age-of-the-universe big.

Comment: Related: [Is there a closed-form function to convert itertools combination into an index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73656031/674039)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have authored a package in `R` called `RcppAlgos` that has functions specifically for this task.

### TL;DR

Use `comboRank` from `RcppAlgos`.

### Details

In the article that @wim linked to, you will see that this procedure is often called *ranking* and as many have pointed out, this boils down to counting.

In the `RcppAlgos` package there are several ranking functions for ranking various structures (e.g. `partitionsRank` for ranking integer partitions). We will use `comboRank` for the task at hand:

```r
library(RcppAlgos)

## Generate random combination from 1:35 of length 4
set.seed(42)
small_random_comb = sort(sample(35, 4))

## Print the combination
small_random_comb
#> [1]  1  4 10 25

## Ranking the combination with comboRank (See ?comboRank for more info).
## N.B. for the ranking functions, we must provide the source vector to rank appropriately
idx = comboRank(small_random_comb, v = 35)

##  Remember, R is base 1.
idx
#> [1] 1179

## Generate all combinations to confirm
all_combs = comboGeneral(35, 4)

## Same result
all_combs[idx, ]
#> [1]  1  4 10 25
```

### Efficiency

The functions are very efficient as well. They are written in `C++` and use the `gmp` library for handling large numbers.

Are they efficient enough for the very large case `n = 1000000` and `r = 10000` (or even `r = 30000`)?

```r
set.seed(97)
large_random_comb = sort(sample(1e6, 1e4))

head(large_random_comb)
#> [1]  76 104 173 608 661 828

tail(large_random_comb)
#> [1] 999684 999731 999732 999759 999824 999878

system.time(lrg_idx <- comboRank(large_random_comb, v = 1e6))
#>   user  system elapsed 
#>  2.036   0.003   2.039

## Let’s not print this number as it is over 20,000 digits
gmp::log10.bigz(lrg_idx)
#> [1] 24318.49

## And for r = 30000 we have:
set.seed(123)
really_large_random_comb = sort(sample(1e6, 3e4))
system.time(really_lrg_idx <- comboRank(really_large_random_comb, v = 1e6))
#>   user  system elapsed 
#>  4.942   0.003   4.945 
gmp::log10.bigz(really_lrg_idx)
#> [1] 58514.98
```

Under 5 seconds ain't that bad!

We can use `comboSample`, which essentially “unranks” when we use the `sampleVec` argument, for confirmation:

```r
check_large_comb = comboSample(1e6, 1e4, sampleVec = lrg_idx)

## Sense comboSample returns a matrix, we must convert to a vector before we compare
identical(as.vector(check_large_comb), large_random_comb)
#> [1] TRUE
```

### What about Python?

And if you need this in `python`, we can make use of `rpy2`. Here is a snippet from a Jupyter Notebook:

```
#> Cell 0
-------------------------------------------------------
import rpy2
import random
from itertools import combinations

mylist = range(0,35) 
r = 4
combinationslist = list(combinations(mylist, r))
combo = random.choice(combinationslist)
combo
-------------------------------------------------------
#> Out[25]: (1, 25, 30, 31)

#> Cell 1
-------------------------------------------------------
## Convert it to a list to ease the transition to R
lst_combo = list(combo)
-------------------------------------------------------

#> Cell 2
-------------------------------------------------------
%load_ext rpy2.ipython
-------------------------------------------------------

#> Cell 3
-------------------------------------------------------
%%R -i lst_combo -o idx
​
library(RcppAlgos)
idx = comboRank(lst_combo, v = 0:34)
-------------------------------------------------------

#> Cell 4
-------------------------------------------------------
idx[0]
-------------------------------------------------------
#> Out[39]: 11347

#> Cell 5
-------------------------------------------------------
## R is base 1, so we subtract 1
combinationslist[idx[0] - 1]
-------------------------------------------------------
#> Out[40]: (1, 25, 30, 31)
```

### Addendum - Key Idea in Ranking Algorithm

Even if we were to translate the excellent algorithm outlined by @wim to a compiled language, we would still not be anywhere close to tackling the large cases presented here. That is because successive calls to any combinatorial function, no matter how optimized, are expensive.

Instead, we take advantage of the fact that this algorithm relies on very subtle differences on each iteration. For example, what if we wanted to calculate the following 3 numbers:

1. *nCr(20, 15)* = 15504
2. *nCr(19, 14)* = 11628
3. *nCr(18, 13)* = 8568

Given the formula for *nCr*:

> *n! / (r! * (n - r)!)*

With this we can use the result in 1 to get the result in step 2 with only two operations and we can use this result to get the result in step 3 in only two operations as well! Observe:

```
(15504 * 15) / 20 = 11628
(11628 * 14) / 19 = 8568
```

This is the key idea behind most of the ranking/unranking algorithms in `RcppAlgos`.

I'm not sure of an elegant way to get to the `C++` code in `RcppAlgos` from `python`. Probably the best solution if you don't want to deal with `rpy2` is to adapt the algorithms below to your personal needs:
https://github.com/jwood000/RcppAlgos/blob/main/src/RankCombination.cpp

Comment: Nice. How hard would it be to hook into the c++ code directly from Python, rather than muck around with rpy2?

Comment: @wim, see my update. Maybe you can use these ideas to get an even larger speed up.

Comment: Incredible, thank you!

Comment: If it's already 5 seconds in cpp, I think translating the same idea into Python has no hope of being fast enough here  :)

Comment: An idea for more speed could be to wrap `RankCombination.cpp` into a Python extension module by using [pybind11](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) or similar, but it sounds as though the O.P. is not too bothered by a detour through rpy2.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [Combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system#Place_of_a_combination_in_the_ordering) wikipedia article.

This is what I've come up with in Python:

```
from math import comb

def combo_index(combo, n):
    result = 0
    i = 0
    for j, item in enumerate(combo):
        k = len(combo) - j
        result += comb(n - i, k)
        result -= comb(n - item, k)
        i += item - i + 1
    return result
```

Demo using your example where *n=35*:

```
>>> len(combinationslist)
52360
>>> combo = random.choice(combinationslist)
>>> combo
(15, 17, 23, 28)
>>> combinationslist[combo_index(combo, 35)]
(15, 17, 23, 28)
```

Here's a recursive approach

```
def combo_index_r(combo, n):
    k = len(combo)
    if k == 0 or k == n:
        return 0
    if k == 1:
        return combo[0]
    combo = tuple(x - 1 for x in combo)
    if combo[0] == -1:
        return combo_index_r(combo[1:], n - 1)
    return comb(n - 1, k - 1) + combo_index_r(combo, n - 1)
```

Comment: This is a lovely approach! It won't work for n=1000000 and r=10000 though. I wonder if there is some way of doing this?

Comment: @mattmoore_bioinfo I took a look for some optimizations and was able to make a 40x speedup by removing the nested loop. I'm not sure if it will be fast enough even now though, that n and r is pretty big. You would probably want to look at a C extension rather than doing this in Python code.